# Sending data/object to ajax

Tags: java, ajax, json, servlets, gson

How could I send data to a ajax call, after converting an object to `json`?

```
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
   response.setContentType("text/plain");
   PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
   LinkedList list = new LinkedList();
   list.add("first");
   list.add("second");
   list.add("third");
   Gson gson = new Gson();
   gson.toJson(list);
   writer.println("From servlet");
}
```

Ajax:

```
$.ajax( {
                    url : 'http://localhost:8081/Football/SendToAjax',
                    type : 'GET'
                })
                .done(function(message) {
                    alert(message);
                }).
                fail(function(message) {
                    alert(message);
                });
```

Comment: you can use as message[0] and more indexes. as i mentioned in answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write back the String that gson.toJson() returns. Additionally you can set the proper content type in your response.

```
   String out = gson.toJson(list);
   response.setContentType("application/json");
   writer.println(out);
```

Comment: How could I receive at the jquery end?

Comment: Set the dataType property to json and use the success() callback function (rather than .done) to directly access the response as a js object.                               success:function (responseTxt, status, jqxhr){  //responseTxt.someProperty;}

Answer (score 1):

you can also write in JSONObject as below

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
json.put("list", list);
writer = response.getWriter();
writer.println(json.toString());
```

and then you can use it in your function in ajax as:

```
$.ajax({
type: 'GET',
url: urlPath,
dataType : "json",
success: function(message){// message is returned message that was written in json
 // use data as message[0]
   for(i = 0; i <message.length; i++){
       alert(message[i]);
 }
 }
 }
 );
```

Answer (score 1):

use `dataType:"json",` in ajax

```
$.ajax( {
url : 'http://localhost:8081/Football/SendToAjax',
type : 'GET',
dataType:"json"
})
.done(function(message) {
alert(message);
}).
fail(function(message) {
alert(message);
});
```

In servlet

```
JSONObject object = new JSONObject();

object.accumulate("list", list);
```